# How to save integers in int format in dataframe.to_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, export-to-csv

I have created a dataframe with values from a list like below:

```
myDataframe= pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in myList.items() }).fillna('')
```

I have some IDs in a dataframe which are like 45333, 4556676. So, when I save this dataframe to a csv file using to_csv() function,but it saves it as 45333.0, 4556676.0 rather than 45333.

Below is the code:

```
export_csv = myDataframe.to_csv (r'/home/myData/new.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

I tried to add `float_format = none`in the `to_csv()` function. But, this has no effect.

Can someone please tell me what the issue is?
I need to save those ids in the form it is in. Not extra float bytes.

Comment: Can you share the dataframe content? Do you have Na values in the column? Usually when you have NAs such conversion happens, try to fillna(0) to fill them by 0 "before" the column is converted to float.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert those values to int like so:

`df.id = df.id.astype(int)`
And then save the dataframe via `to_csv()` method

Comment: But, say I have an ID  with number like 6475738975. If I do this `df.id.astype(int)` , won't the number get trimmed ?

Comment: I dont think it will get trimmed. You could also try `astype(str)` then. It will have same appearance in csv file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. This is creating a float value in the dataframe.id newly.  The original dataframe has no float values. It shows the exact numbers in the dataframe. But, while saving to csv file, it is changing to number.0

Comment: Okay, so this is happening because the id which I used in the list is getting converted to float. So, before storing the value in the dataframe, I changed the value of that id in the List to `astype(str)`. Now it is working fine!